How to get path in sync way?
I want to create my sqlite db in phone.
All ways that I found to determine correct path for db
are async.
I need to have way of doing that in sync way?
How to do this?

Cannot you await your Future inside main() before calling any runApp?

It solved my issue. Put this as an answer with code snippet so I can accept it.

great it works, feel free to post a self-answer then ;-)
